# Reduce margin bottom and margin top on mobile

Tags: css, margin

in this [website](https://cuna-women.ch/events-test/)  I am trying to reduce the margin at the bottom and at the top **ON MOBILE** between the banner and the text.

If you have a look on smartphone and tablet looks like the banner has some margin top and bottom.

This is my CSS:

```
.page-id-996 .pageHeaderImg {
    background-size: contain;
    padding-top: none !important;
}
```

If you have a look at the other page it works properly.

I tried with `margin-bottom: 0px !important;` without any results.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `margin-bottom: none` is an invalid value. `margin-bottom: 0` is valid. The same goes with `padding` values

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the property of background must be cover not contain

Comment: but if i set cover then on mobile the picture cover the whole height of the div. Is possible to make it contain on mobile?

Comment: Background:contain doesn´t fill the hole layer just fill the width, you can put position center top for example and it will be stuck to the header, in your case the position must set at 140px more o less from top because I think the layer ".pageHeaderImg" has 900px height and cover all the screen including header, so you will have to fix that if you want to remove that blank space